# PERL: Matching multiple patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I have a block of text that looks like this

```
 Log Message(500).
    'Time': 1412207847
    'Name': John
    'blah some text
    'blah 2': some text
    'Priority': 5
    'Header':   Oct  1 19:00:12 2014  
    'Message':  Multiple lines of text here
```

I am trying to extract the Name, Header, and Message. I have gotten it to extract the Header and Message, but I am having trouble getting it to get the Name as well now.

Here is how I get the Header and Message

```
   my ($header, $message) = /
                    ^ \s+ Log[ ]Message .* \n
                    \s+ 'Header': \s+ (\S.*) \n
                    \s+ 'Message': \s+ (\S.*) \n \n $
            /xms;
```

Here is how I was tring to get the name as well, but it doesnt work.

```
my ($name, $header, $message) = /
                    ^ \s+ Log[ ]Message .* \n     # many lines
                    \s* 'Name': \s+ (\S.*) \n
                    \s+ 'Header': \s+ (\S.*) \n
                    \s+ 'Message': \s+ (\S.*) \n \n $
            /xms;
```

EDIT: I want to get JUST the values. So I want it to return

```
John
Oct  1 19:00:12 2014
Multiple lines of text here
```

Comment: If the string really is delimited by new line then just split on newline then compare each to the pieces you want.

Comment: You have too many whitespace characters. It should work if you change " \s+ " (note the spaces...) to just "\s+".

Comment: Does the line `'blah some text` really have no closing `'` and no `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the whole file at a time :

```
$ perl -0ne '
    print $1, $2, $3, $4 if
        /
            \047 Name    \047:\s*(.*?\n).*?
            \047 Header  \047:\s*(.*?\n).*?
            \047 Message \047:\s*(.*)
        /sx
' file
```

Or using named back-reference and a HASH slice :

```
$ perl -0ne '
    print @+{qw/Name Header Message/} if 
    /
        \047 Name    \047:\s*(?<Name>    .*?\n).*?
        \047 Header  \047:\s*(?<Header>  .*?\n).*?
        \047 Message \047:\s*(?<Message> .*?\n)
    /sx
' file
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
John
Oct  1 19:00:12 2014  
Multiple lines of text here
```

Comment: Thats looking good. I updated my original question, I actually want it to just return the value IE everything after the colon